# Jquery drag revert on drop to specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I currently have a layout that uses Jquery UI Drag and Drop.. I have seen the code on the Jquery website for reverting but I am not sure how I would go about detecting if a div has been dropped on a certain div and if it has been then to revert it.

Basically I have 2 divs and I only want the drag/drop to be able to drop inside one, if it doesn't get dropped in the right one then it is reverted :)

**Script:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function shift(parent){
$("#"+parent).draggable({ handle: ".item", accept: "#floor", containment: "#floor", scroll: false, stack:"#floor div" });
}
</script>
```

**Draggable:**

```
<div id="drag" class="ui-widget-content" onmousedown="shift('example')"> </div>
```

**DIVs**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="floor"> </div>
    <div id="other"> </div>
</div>
```

The draggable is within the container but I only want it to be dropped within floor and not other.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Can you please post some of your code?

Comment: Sorry, yes, added in for you :)

Comment: Hey Andrew I might be able to help you out: so what is the behaviour you are trying? i.e. <div> `flloor & other` shoule not be draggable and what is the relevance of `drag` div, sorry if I sound thick, :)

Comment: The relevance of drag is because people are able to drag other divs but I want to restrain them to only be able to drop what they drag into "floor" and not into "other". If they drag into other then it will be reverted otherwise if they drag into floor it will dropped successfully :)

Comment: @Andrew Okies wait I will write you a demo soon; gotch you hopefully :P

Comment: Cool @Andrew I have updated a post. Hope it help :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hiya Andrew **Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/BYsnc/

Hope this will help

Good read: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable

Behaviour: When user drag `drag me` to `floor` it will allow else if you drag it to `other` it wont B-)

**Explanation**

**JQuery Code**

**// Make Floor Div as droppable**

```
$('#floor').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit'
});
```

**// Now make drag div as draggable**

```
$('#drag').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    stop: function(){
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
    }
});
```

**// Finally tell drag that about their Droppable property**

```
$('#drag').droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event,ui){
        ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
    }
});
​
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you have been such a great help and this was just what I was looking for :D

Comment: I wanted successful drop callback function